# Sync remote database (msSQL) with local database(SQLite) using EF core

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework, xamarin

does anybody know, if there is a way to synchronize two databases?

I have two devices:

- A desktop with a wpf application, running a msSQL database with Entity Framework
- A mobile device with a xamarin app, running a SQLite database with Entity Framework Core

Both databases are using the same schema.

I would like to sync the data bidirectional. 
I tried it with SQLite-sync.com, but it's not possible to use it with Entity Framework Core.

Does anybody know any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i believe it can be achieved by using syncadapter in Xamarin

Comment: Maybe WCF would be an option in reading the JSON in the other side for updating.

Comment: Did you get this functionality implemented by chance?